# How can I analyze programmatically to undersand there is many-to-many relationship between two tables?

Tags: c#, java, sql, database, many-to-many

When I look a Db schema or a diagram it is obvious to figure out if there is a many-to-many relationship between two tables.

But how can I analyze this from the computer point of view? What kind of test algorithm the code should follow to decide there is a many-to-many relatiopnship between TableA and TableB?

I would appreciate if you can suggest a way without using any specific language based methods or helpers.

Something like:

> "If 'this' is true, then there is absolutely a many-to-many
>   relationship between 2 tables."

So what should I write at the place of 'this' ?

Thanks

Comment: Erm, the database should know that already. Just query it.

Comment: @Joey: Imagine you are writing a code template in MyGeneration and while you are working on TableA, you want to test if this table has any many-to-many relationship between itself and another table. But I am more interested in how should be a logical test to be generated to understand this. Forget about what the Db knows. (I don't know if it is possible anyway)

Comment: Nice question! It would be even nicer, if you had added the opposite direction: `"If 'this' is false, then there is absolutely not a many-to-many relationship between 2 tables."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a table C not equal to A or B with foreign keys corresponding to primary keys in A and B.

Just a guess. I think it's true, though; it certainly happens when you want a m2m relationship... When it just happens to occur, I think you are OK reading a m2m relationship into it.

Comment: Note: this is sufficient, but possibly unnecessary.

Comment: No, that won't work. An order might have a foreign key to a billing address (TableA) and another foreign key to shipping address (TableB), but that doesn't mean there's a M:N relationship between billing addresses and shipping addresses.

Comment: There exists *1 or many tables on a relationship path between A and B* where those tables are not A or B; and where the relationship at A and B is 'many'. A can be equal to B.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very difficult problem, because you can infer a many-to-many relationship that is nonsense in the context of your application.

For example, a table, Person, could have a foreign key to table, PostalAddress (describing where they live), and a foreign key to table CoffeeMachine (describing which coffee machine they're allowed to use).

Relying on the presence of a table with foreign keys to two other tables may lead you to infer that there is a many-to-many relationship between PostalAddress and CoffeeMachine (coffee machines used by people living at particular addresses) which is likely to be irrelevant in the context of the application.

You shouldn't rely on link tables having only foreign keys to other tables, either, as there can be other attributes that describe something about the relationship (e.g. the role that a person performs on a particular project).

While we use link tables to model many-to-many relationships, I don't think there's anything about such a table that allows you to infer the inverse.

Comment: I partially disagree. In the case you describe, I think there is a many-to-many relationship between `CoffeeMachine`s and `PostalAddress`es. But I agree that this relationship will most probably be useless (unless you are in CSI and have to identify a killer knowing he drank from a certain Coffee Machine and you can only analyze the dumps from various Postal Addresses.) And then convince the jury that **there is** a relationship.

Comment: Indeed, I was careful to not imply that there wasn't a relationship there, but that it was (probably) nonsense. If you used this logic to reverse-engineer a database into a model, it would lead to a potentially hopelessly confusing model!

Answer (score 1):

> "If 'this' is true, then there is absolutely a many-to-many
> relationship between 2 tables."
>
> So what should I write at the place of 'this' ?

- There's a third table.
- It includes at least two foreign keys: at least one candidate key from TableA
  and at least one candidate key from TableB.
- There's either a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint or a `NOT NULL UNIQUE` constraint on
  that pair of foreign keys.

Comment: these are nice and probably sufficient conditions. But they are not necessary, right?

Comment: I think all of them are necessary for an algorithm to deduce "M:N" from existing tables. That was the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a link table consisting of only foreign keys connecting two other tables, and neither of the columns have a unique constraint, then you have a many-to-many relationship.  if either of your tables directly references the other, you have a one(or zero) to many relationship.

Comment: A table that implements a M:N relationship need not consist of only foreign keys. It needs foreign keys to TableA and TableB, but it could well have other columns, too.

Comment: then it's not a link table, but technically true.  Not good database design, but possible.  The important points are the two foreign key columns and the lack of a unique constraint on either column.

Comment: @Catcall: your answer is also a little inaccurate.  You do not need a unique constraint on the key pair.  Again, good practice, but not necessary for a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: The important points are two foreign keys (might be more than one column each) and either a `PRIMARY KEY` or `NOT NULL UNIQUE` constraint on the pair of foreign keys.

Comment: You don't need a primary key or not null unique constraint on the pair.  If there were duplicates it would still be a many-to-many relationship... and also a headache.

Comment: But in the absence of a candidate key, an algorithm can't determine whether you omitted a UNIQUE constraint on the first FK, a UNIQUE constraint on the second FK, or a UNIQUE constraint on the pair of FKs (the only way to identify M:N). An algorithm can't deduce much of anything from a keyless table.

Comment: All of this is true, but it does not change the fact that in the absence of every sort of constraint, if you have a table with 2 distinct columns representing foreign keys against 2 other tables, you have a many-to-many relationship defined... everything is is just good sense.

Comment: @Catcall let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1558/discussion-between-jeremy-and-catcall)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite interesting but it asks only for a sufficient condition. I think it would be even more interesting if a **necessary and sufficient** condition was asked.

> When I look a Db schema or a diagram it is **obvious** to figure out if there is a many-to-many relationship between two tables.

Is it? Try this one:

- Is there a many-to-many relationship between `Child` and `Test` ?
- Is there a many-to-many relationship between `Parent` and `Test` ?

the db:

```
Parent
------
id
PRIMARY KEY: id

Child
-----
id
parentid
... other data
PRIMARY KEY: id
FOREIGN KEY: parentid
    REFERENCES Parent(id)

Test
----
testid
... other data
PRIMARY KEY: testid

BestChild
---------
testid
parentid
childid
... other data
PRIMARY KEY: (testid, parentid)
FOREIGN KEY: (childid, parentid)
    REFERENCES Child(id, parentid)
FOREIGN KEY: testid
    REFERENCES Test(id)
```